# Question about updating service data directly in component

Tags: angular, service, state, behaviorsubject

I have this service:

```
export class MyService {
  private mySubject: BehaviorSubject<MyObject[]> = new BehaviorSubject<MyObject[]>([]);
  private myObjs: MyObject[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get myObjs$() {
    return this.mySubject.asObservable();
  }

  getObjects() {
    const mock = new MockObjects();
    this.mats = mock.getMockObjs();
    this._notify();
  }

  clearSelections() {
    this.myObjs.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.added = false;
    });
    this._notify();
  }

  private _notify() {
    // Deep clone the array in order to keep the source data immutable.
    const objs = this.myObjs.map((obj) => ({ ...obj }));
    this.mySubject.next(objs);
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is providing an observable for an array of MyObjects. I do this in order to display all of them in one component easily. At the same time, I want only the service to have access to updating data for any MyObject. But I don't see how I can enforce that if I'm providing an array of MyObjects to each subscriber. For example, if MyObject has a property called added, I don't want the component updating the added property directly. The service should have a setter for updating the added value for 1 MyObject and then push the new values to all components.

So my question is ... what is stopping one of the components from changing one of the MyObject instances directly in the component? Even if I create a deep clone of the array and objects in it before pushing new values from the service, if 1 component makes a change to its copy, wouldn't it affect the other components still? Of course, the data in the service wouldn't be affected. I feel like I am not doing something correctly here but can't figure out what it is. I've done lots of research and can't find a clear answer as far as what is the best practice here. Should I be providing an observable for an array of objects here?

EDIT: Maybe the answer is that components *should* have their own copy of the data and if they update it, then that is OK? It just means it won't be updated via the service. I guess I'm just worried about having multiple copies of the data floating around and eventually causing bugs.

Comment: You should definitely have your entities updates centralized in the service, you don't want to have your components making unnoticed changes to the data as it may lead to future maintenance problems. I'm wondering why do you need an observable and cannot get by with methods such as GetAll() and Update()?

Comment: Yeah, I am reviewing my code again and realized the same thing. I was using the observables in order to use the async pipe in my component (in case they want to reload the data). But I'm thinking maybe this is overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish at the moment. Going to try a non-observable approach and see how that goes.

Comment: Got it working within 30 minutes and it is much simpler. It's a bit ugly since I have to do a subscription on a subject inside a component. I hate that I have to do that but it does the job for now. Maybe later I can refactor it to use a BehaviorSubject/data store type pattern like above.